# ffmpeg - Why does concatenating .ts videos through .txt fail from \folder\ but work from \folder\subfolder\?

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation, subdirectory

I have a bunch of .ts videofiles that I want to merge into a single file so I can convert it to a .mp4 video.

The .ts files are in a folder "E:\videotest" like:

```
E:\videotest\0.ts  
E:\videotest\1.ts  
[...]  
E:\videotest\100.ts
```

I used a PowerShell command to output the filepaths in a .txt file:

```
foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem .\*.ts) {echo "file '$i'" >> mylist.txt}
```

The resulting mylist.txt looks like:

```
file 'E:\videotest\0.ts'  
file 'E:\videotest\1.ts'  
[...]    
file 'E:\videotest\100.ts'
```

When I run the command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe "0" -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls" -i "E:\videotest\concat\mylist.txt" -c copy "E:\videotest\concat\combined_video.ts"
```

I get the error:

> Line 1: unknown keyword ' ■f'
> E:\videotest\concat\mylist.txt:
> Invalid data found when processing input

But if I add a subfolder layer to the files like this:

```
E:\videotest\0\0.ts  
E:\videotest\1\1.ts  
[...]  
E:\videotest\100\100.ts
```

And change mylist.txt to:

```
file 'E:\videotest\0\0.ts'  
file 'E:\videotest\1\1.ts'  
[...]    
file 'E:\videotest\100\100.ts'
```

The same ffmpeg command will work and create the combined_video.ts file.

Why does converting work with the subfolder structure but not from the main folder?

How do I adjust the ffmpeg command to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the problem was the encoding of the "mylist.txt" file. For some reason it was encoded as "UCS-2 LE BOM". After setting it to "UTF-8" I was able to concatenate the files.